# JSON value of type NSnull cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: android, ios, json, firebase, react-native

I have a strange error on my react-native Firebase APL.

react-native run-android works fine without error.

but react-native run-ios failed with JSON value of type NSnull cannot be converted to NSString.

source code is as follows.(main and signup class to authentication work on firebase)

I think Firebase Class has different ACT on ios and Android to convert JSON to text.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Shoji

main

// Initialize the firebase app here and pass it to other components as needed. Only initialize on startup.

```
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var GiftedMessenger = require('react-native-gifted-messenger');

    let styles = {}

    class Pricing extends Component {

    constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = {

    page: null

    };

    /* this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items'); */

    }

    componentWillMount(){

    // We must asynchronously get the auth state, if we use currentUser here, it'll be null

    const unsubscribe = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

    // If the user is logged in take them to the accounts screen

    if (user != null) {

    this.setState({page: Account});

    console.log('(user != null)')

    return;

    }

    // otherwise have them login

    console.log('(user != Login)')

    this.setState({page: Login});

    // unsubscribe this observer

    unsubscribe();

    });

    }

    render() {

    if (this.state.page) {

    return (

    // Take the user to whatever page we set the state to.

    // We will use a transition where the new page will slide in from the right.

    <Navigator

    initialRoute={{component: this.state.page}}

    configureScene={() => {

    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

    }}

    renderScene={(route, navigator) => {

    if(route.component){

    // Pass the navigator the the page so it can navigate as well.

    // Pass firebaseApp so it can make calls to firebase.

    return React.createElement(route.component, { navigator, firebaseApp});

    }

    }} />

);

} else {

return (

// Our default loading view while waiting to hear back from firebase
```

Comment: The error seems quite specific. The question should try to do the same.

Comment: CLASS firebase called my APL is as follows.

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const unsubscribe = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
   

  this.props.firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
   

    const userData = this.props.firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;
  

 
            source={{uri: this.state.user.photoURL}} />
        
  
    // logout, once that is complete, return the user to the login screen.
    this.props.firebaseApp.auth().signOut().then(() => {

Answer (score 0):

I deeply debug in this BUG.
At last I found it as follows.

```
<Image
source={{uri: 'this.state.user.photoURL'}} <<<single quotation was added. 
style={styles.image}
/>
```

I did not expect like this kind of error.

Thanks Shoji

Comment: Why ios and Android do different action without single quotation?

Answer (score 0):

took help from @itagaki. Error was removed after replacing single quote with double quote in following code

```
const BoldText = (props) => <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{props.children}</Text>;
```